# Adding Validation List with VBA is unstable

Tags: vba, excel

In **SetWS** sheet I have the following code in Worksheet_Deactivate:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Dim ActWS, SetWS  As Worksheet
    Set ActWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Activity_Plan")
    Set SetWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
With ActWS.Range("J11:J20").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Settings!$AS$10:$AS$20"                                  '
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With                                                                                             '
End Sub
```

In **RepWS** sheet (where I only create a couple of graphs) I have the following code in Worksheet_Activate:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim ScopeWS, RepWS, ActWS, SetWS As Worksheet
    Set ScopeWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Scope")
    Set RepWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rep")
    Set ActWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Activity_Plan")
    Set SetWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
LRowScopeE = ScopeWS.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If SetWS.Range("W17") > SetWS.Range("W18") Then                                                 '
    MsgBox ("bla bla")
    Exit Sub
End If
RepWS.ChartObjects("Diagramm 3").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Scope!$M$4"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Scope!$M$11:$M$" & LRowScopeE
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Scope!$E$11:$E$" & LRowScopeE
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Scope!$P$4"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Scope!$P$11:$P$" & LRowScopeE
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=Scope!$U$4"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=Scope!$T$11:$T$" & LRowScopeE
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#.##0 €"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#.##0 €"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 14").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Settings!$CJ$10"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Settings!$CJ$11:$CJ$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Settings!$CI$11:$CI$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Settings!$CK$10"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Settings!$CK$11:$CK$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I switch from SetWS to RepWS, it throws an error

> "Application defined or object defined error"

and highlights in SetWS the following:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Settings!$AS$10:$AS$20"
```

Switching between any other pair of sheets in this file does not cause this error (e.g. switching SetWS to any other sheet is OK).

**UPDATE:** I notice I more thing - As soon as I activate RepWS once, any further attempt to switch from SetWS to RepWS throws an error. Something is wrong with RepWS code...

Comment: I'm not sure about that but could it be that the routine is just not finished when switching? try to add a msgBox at the end of both subs and switch only when the msgBox popped up....

Comment: I just noticed it happens from time to time. The deactivation of SetWS is not finished, giving the error above. I have some more Validation lists in SetWS, and when I delete the one described above, another Validation list starts giving the same error. So perhaps something is not stable with Validation list

Comment: Moreover, the funny thing is that when I go with Debug through Worksheet_Deactivate - it gives no error

Comment: I have never actually used .validation so I don't really understand it. This was just a guess and it's always good if you can exclude sources of errors :)

Comment: it could be the code is processing faster than the actions can. Try placing a `Wait` or `Sleep` or `DoEvents` command in the end of the `Worksheet_Deactivate` code. Sometimes giving Excel some breathing room in the code does the trick.

Comment: The worksheet_deactivate event sub sets the validation for a range, but doesn't use the `LRowSetAS` which is used in the by the debugger highlighted code. Are you sure the code highlighted is actually in the SetWS sheet?

Comment: @SilentRevolution yes, sorry - to narrow down the possible problem range I changed the initial code above so it does not use LRowSetAS (instead of it I simply set 20)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Waiting 10 sec did not help. But I notice I more thing - When I initially open the doc, I see **RepWS** (by default I save the file on this sheet before exiting). If I go to **SetWS** and back - no error. If again - error. Moreover, if initially I switch between **RepWS** and any other sheet and back to **RepWS**, the next try to switch **RepWS>SetWS>RepWS** gives error. That means running **RepWS** `worksheet_activate` code twice or more makes something bad... BUT only affecting **SetWS**. I have 3 more sheets with `worksheet_activate` and they continue working fine

Comment: On an unrelated sidenote, I'd advise avoiding the used of `active(workbook/sheet/...), .activate/.select methods, and .selction property`

Comment: @SilentRevolution Thanks, but for creating a chart I could not find an alternative. If I replace `ActiveChart` with `PitWS.ChartObjects("Diagramm 3")` - it gives an error

Comment: Change it to `PitWs.ChartObjects("Diagram 3").Chart` then you can avoid the `activechart`

Comment: @SilentRevolution Thank you! That was exactly the issue. When I changed all Activate to your suggestion - the code now works fine, and no error happens when I try to switch between RepWS and SetWS. Now I understand why I should avoid Select and Activate - an error out of thin air...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the use of `Active(Workbook/Sheet/Cell/Chart/...)`, the `.Activate/.Select` method and the `.Selection` property.

your worksheet_activate sub, might look something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim ScopeWS, RepWS, ActWS, SetWS As Worksheet

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ScopeWS = .Sheets("Scope")
        Set RepWS = .Sheets("Rep")
        Set ActWS = .Sheets("Activity_Plan")
        Set SetWS = .Sheets("Settings")
    End With

    LRowScopeE = ScopeWS.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If SetWS.Range("W17") > SetWS.Range("W18") Then                                                 '
        MsgBox ("bla bla")
    Else
        With RepWS
        'Diagram 3
            With .ChartObjects("Diagram 3").Chart
            'Series 1
                With .SeriesCollection(1)
                    .Name = "=Scope!$M$4"
                    .Values = "=Scope!$M$11:$M$" & LRowSco
                    .XValues = "=Scope!$E$11:$E$" & LRowScopeE
                End With
            'Series 2
                With .SeriesCollection(2)
                    .Name = "=Scope!$P$4"
                    .Values = "=Scope!$P$11:$P$" & LRowScopeE
                End With
            'Series 3
                With .seriescolection(3)
                    .Name = "=Scope!$U$4"
                    .Values = "=Scope!$T$11:$T$" & LRowScopeE
                End With
            'Layout
                With .Axes(xlValue)
                    .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
                    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#.##0 €"
                End With
                .FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#.##0 €"
            End With
        'Diagram 14
            With .ChartObjects("Diagram 14").Chart
            'Series 1
                With .SeriesCollection(1)
                    .Name = "=Settings!$CJ$10"
                    .Values = "=Settings!$CJ$11:$CJ$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
                    .XValues = "=Settings!$CI$11:$CI$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
                End With
            'Series 2
                With .SeriesCollection(2)
                    .Name = "=Settings!$CK$10"
                    .Values = "=Settings!$CK$11:$CK$" & SetWS.Range("CL8").Value
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there a way to avoid using ActiveCell when a code has to insert row below the ActiveCell? I have `ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove`

Comment: It is possible but at the moment There is not enough information. How is the cell activated? In general, `~.Cell(10,1).Activate` and `ActiveCell.Offset(1).~` is combined into `~.Cell(10, 1).Offset(1).~`

Comment: The worksheet is a table with the button. By clicking the button, a new row is inserted right under the cell, which is currently active

Comment: I think that this is one of those cases where you can't avoid it since the code has to run on a row chosen by the user. if there is a pattern to where you want the row inserted you might create a loop which iterates through a list and inserts a row based on cell contents or similar. In any case I'd declare a range like `Dim rngSelected as Range` and then `Set rngSelected = ActiveCell` and then use `rngSelected` instead of `ActiveCell`.